# Como utilizar with no retorno de um DB::Select - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Para pegar a informação, esta sendo usando um `DB::RAW` assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é no `Repository`. Já no Controller, gostaria de usar o `with` para trazer os relacionamentos feitos no Model:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o `DB::select` retorna por padrão um `array`, com a consulta feita.

É possível utilizar isso ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Como você está fazendo um `selectRaw`, você deve descrever as propriedades no select e acessa-los direto `$orders->campo`;

Comment: Não é possivel!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, tudo indica que é possível: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855116/how-to-create-a-eloquent-model-instance-from-a-raw-object
Mas estou trabalhando em um L4, então esta menos simples do que isso ai rs

Comment: @DavidDias com `DB::select` diretamente não é possível, isso é um fato, agora ficar escrevendo código a mais pode resolver o seu problema, mas, de acordo com a pergunta, e no meu entender isso tem que verificar o desempenho visto que o retorno já está montado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta do Jilcimar resolve para os casos onde você pode fazer a consulta a partir do próprio Model, no meu caso eu queria fazer a combinação de `Joins` de primeira.

Para resolver isso, o `Laravel` possui um método chamado `Hydrate`, que converte uma `Query Builder` para um objeto `Eloquent`.

Se, após o processo, você precisar ainda fazer algum relacionamento por dentro do Model, você precisará utilizar o `->load()`ao invés do comum `->with()`.

No meu caso, a solução gerou este método:

```
public function pending_orders()
{
    $results = DB::select("

        SELECT orders.*,

        orders.id as orders_id,
        invoices.id as invoice_id,
        invoices.state as invoice_status,

        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nfes.id  SEPARATOR ',') As nfe_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT nfes.status  SEPARATOR ',') As nfe_status,

        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT packages.id  SEPARATOR ',') As package_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT shipments.id  SEPARATOR ',') As shipment_id

        FROM orders

        LEFT JOIN invoices ON orders.id = invoices.order_id
        LEFT JOIN nfes ON invoices.id = nfes.invoice_id
        LEFT JOIN packages ON orders.id = packages.order_id
        LEFT JOIN shipments ON packages.id = shipments.package_id

        WHERE

        orders.deleted_at is NULL AND
        orders.state != 'in_checkout'
        AND (invoices.state != 'paid' OR invoices.state is NULL)
        AND  nfes.invoice_id NOT IN (SELECT invoice_id FROM nfes WHERE status = 'aprovado')

        GROUP BY orders_id, invoice_id, invoice_status
        ORDER BY nfes.id DESC

        ");
    return Order::hydrate($results);
}
```

E na sequência para simplificar relacionamento adicionais:

```
$orders = $this->order->pending_orders()->load('items')->load('lineItems')->load('user')->load('packages')->load('invoice');
```

Considere que não há pensamentos sobre boas práticas nesta solução, nem mesmo analise de performance.

No fim das contas eu resolvi de outra maneira, porém, acredito que o tema possa ajudar alguém de alguma forma, pois a conversão da `Query Builder` para o `Eloquent` é algo útil ao meu ver.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que você poderia testar algo parecido com isso

```
Order::select('seu select aqui')->with('sua relação do model Order')->get();
```

Possa ser que funcione, qualquer coisa dê uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757062/laravel-raw-query-and-including-model-relations